# has_many through to yield cross joined result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, cross-join

I am trying to build the multi-level model as demonstrated. When a user creates a campaign they will select some categories and some metros from tables Category and Metro. Those selections will then be placed within two tables as campaign_category and campaign_metro. But upon the creation of those entries I wish for then another table to be populated with the permutation of those combinations within table campaign_category_metro to allow for linking the campaign, the category and metros selected for a user to set a bid price on.

For example say a user creates a campaign that has id 10 and selects category with id 1 and 2, and metros with id 3 and 4. In the tables campaign_category appears:

[image]

and in table campaign_metro appears:

[image]

In campagin_category_metro I want to have those permuted rows from the tables above as:

[image]

Then a user can set a bid on those campaign/metro combinations.

As of now, in creating a campaign, and selecting categories and metros I can get the tables campaign_category and campaign_metro populated but the final table, campaign_category_metro, remains blank. Below is my model as is:

First Level:

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base   
    has_many :campaign_metros, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :metros, through: :campaign_metros

    has_many :campaign_categories, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :categories, through: :campaign_categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :campaign_categories, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :campaigns, through: :campaign_categories
end

class Metro < ActiveRecord::Base   
    has_many :campaign_metros, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :campaigns, through: :campaign_metros
end
```

Second Level (populates, but the relation to campaign_category_metro does nothing):

```
class CampaignCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :campaign
    belongs_to :category

    has_many :campaign_category_metros, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :campaign_metros, through: :campaign_category_metros
end

class CampaignMetro < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :campaign
    belongs_to :metro

    has_many :campaign_category_metros, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :campaign_categories, through: :campaign_category_metros
end
```

Third Level (Nothing shows up upon creation of a campaign):

```
class CampaignCategoryMetro < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :campaign_category
    belongs_to :campaign_metro
end
```

How can I allow for the third level table to be populated with the cross joined result of the tables campaign_category and campaign_metro upon campaign creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would look into hooking a function up on :after_create or :after_initialize,
which sets the cross joined results.

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :add_campaign_category_metros

  def add_campaign_category_metros
    campaign_categories = this.campaign_categories
    campaign_metros = this.campaign_categories

    campaign_categories.each do |cc|
      campaign_metros.each do |cm|
        ccm = CampaignCategoryMetro.new
        ccm.campaign_category = cc
        ccm.campaign_metro = cm
        ccm.save
      end
    end

  end
```

Not sure how you want to populate bid, but that's about what i would try.

Comment: Bid will be populated by the user after the entry has been created. With you suggestion do relations still work between the models?

Comment: Relations should work as they are specified within the models.
All you do is upon creation, create the CampaignCategoryMetro objects.
Might be hard if you allow updating though. I'll check if theres any other possibility for that.

Comment: For this table, I will definitely need updating. Is there perhaps another model layout and relation that would allow the same functionality but simpler implementation?

Comment: It's tricky, the problem is keeping the CampaignCategoryMetro in sync with CampaignCategory & CampaignMetro. I was wondering if you could try using a database view (AR does not care about table or view), but you might have trouble hooking up the bids. It would go in its own table and you would join it on the Database view on campaign_category_id and campaign_metro_id, not sure if that's going to be complex or not. Surely relieves the syncing problem..

Comment: I've been thinking about the problem.

Comment: Here's what I came up with: 
You just hook up an after_create hook onto CampaignCategory and CampaignMetro which create the CampaignCategoryMetro entries for the given object. Then you just need to set the has_many CampaignCategoryMetro association as dependent: destroy (which you already have) and you should be good IMO. All we have to take care of is that the entries are correctly added, if the CampaignCategory or CampaignMetro gets deleted, the dependent: destroy takes care of business anyways. Hope I could help you out, let me know!

Comment: Thank you. How can I work in editing the table as well? In trms of another way to do this, I was thinking of taking your idea but simply relying on the CamapaignCategoryMetroBid table with columns campaign_id, category_id, metro_id and then creating all the entries at once as insert